# ruby on rails server is not running localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, installation

So, I installed the package for Windows at http://railsinstaller.org/

Now I have a cmd with `c:\sites\todo`

If I try to connect to localhost:3000 it is not working. Do I have to install something else? How do I start the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Run `rails server` and read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score -1):

the command was rails s and it is working now.